# Texture pain stencil has right color on UV, but extremely faded on mesh

Tags: texture-painting

I've created a png stencil with transparency. Positioned it and painted it onto the mesh... it looks perfect in the UV, but in the texture paint view it is extremely washed out. You can just barely make out the blue circle. I've included the shader nodes as well. Created an image texture, black, 2048x2048. Went to texture pain. Added a texture, in texture added the png file, set it from repeat to clip. Back in the paint settings, brush is TexDraw, mode is stencil. The brush color is white.

Any idea what would be causing this?! The blend mode on the mix color node is set to add. Changing the factor doesn't help. It either goes away or looks as shown in the image. Been working on this for 2 hours and my brain is fried.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The blend mode on the mix color node is set to add" - this is the problem. Set the Blend mode to "Mix" and then that acts like Photoshop's "Normal" mix mode. "Add" combines the colors to create a lighter color similar to "Screen" but not the exactly the same, but a Stencil should be using "Mix" mostly when just putting the pixels into the target texture.

Comment: Oh, interesting... I didn't realize it behaved that way. Turns out that was 50% of my problem. The other half was when I created the new image texture in the shader, I left the alpha at 1. Dragging that to 0 fixed the other half of the issue.

THANK YOU!